# Trying to establish a audio connection through an RF box for 3.5mm audio jack

Tags: audio-interfaces, rf

I am testing a Bluetooth audio and setting up an RF chamber setup for the audio device and i have a 3.5mm audio jack output from one of these Bluetooth devices which i need to transfer to another RF box using the ports available behind this RF box, it has USB, banana plugs and RF RCA ports(posting pic[image]), what is my best option here? remember i need to convert both ways to take this connection out of the box and back into another similar box, many thanks in advance for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the banana plugs. Ground is common across the black terminals. Tip (of the TRS) can go to the red connector on the left and Ring (of the trs) can go to the red connector on the right. Sleeve is ground, and thus goes to one or both of the black connectors.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the response, sorry i am new to this, am i missing something here? my source connection is a 3.5mm jack(like the one on phones) , not a TRS cable connection, so should i first convert the 3.5mm to TRS using an adapter?

Comment: 3.5mm connectors are Tip Ring Sleeve (TRS) connectors. The "Tip", "Ring" and "Sleeve" describe the three connection points on the plug.